# Problem with retrieving a Session Bean in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, javabeans

I am following this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes but have an issue getting it to work.

I have made the following configuration class.

```
package spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SessionConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Session returnSession() {
        return new Session();
    }
}
```

Then I try to retrieve the bean in another class like this:

```
package spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.controllers;


import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.service.SessionHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.json.Login;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session.Session;



@RestController
@RequestMapping("rest/login")
public class SessionController {
    @Resource(name = "returnSession")
    Session returnSession;
    
    private final String crossorg = "http://localhost:4200/";
    
    @Autowired
    SessionHandler handler;    
    
    
    @GetMapping(value = "test")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = crossorg)
    public String getTest() {        
        return "it was found";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "login", produces = "application/json")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = crossorg)
    public Login attemptLogin(@RequestBody Login payload) {        
        return handler.attemptLogin(payload);
    }
    
}
```

However, this code does not compile.
I get the following error:

spring/boardgame/registerboardgame/service/SessionHandler.java:[26,6] incompatible types: org.springframework.core.io.Resource cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation

I am learning Spring Boot and this is my first program with that framework, so guess there are things I may have missed on the way, but hope someone can help me in seeing what is wrong there?

I first tried to put it into another class like this:

```
package spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.repository.UserRepository;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.json.Login;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.User;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.UserRole;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.model.Role;
import java.util.List;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session.Session;
import spring.boardgame.registerboardgame.session.SessionConfiguration;


@Service
public class SessionHandler {
    @Resource(name = "returnSession")
    Session returnSession;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userrepo;   
    
    @Autowired
    private Session mainsession;
    
    

    
    public Login attemptLogin(Login login){
       
        if(this.mainsession.getUser() == null){
            System.out.println("not logged in");
        }else{
            System.out.println("logged already");
        }
        
        if(login.getPassword() == null || login.getPassword().trim().length() < 3){
            login.setErrormessage("Du må fylle ut et passord.");
            return login;
        }else{          
            List<User> users = userrepo.findByBrukernavnAndPassord(login.getBrukernavn(), login.getPassword());
            if(users.size() == 1){
                User loggedin = users.get(0);
                login.setUserID(loggedin.getId().intValue());
                login.setStatus(0);
                for(UserRole rolle: loggedin.getRoller()){
                    if(rolle.getRole().getId() > login.getStatus()){
                        login.setStatus(rolle.getRole().getId());
                    }
                }
                
                this.mainsession.setUser(loggedin);
                System.out.println("is logging in");
                if(this.mainsession.getUser() == null){
                    System.out.println("not logged in after");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("logged already after");
                }
                return login;
            }else{
                login.setErrormessage("Du fylte og feil brukernavn og/eller passord. Vennligst forsøk igjen.");
                return login;
            }
        }

    }

    
}
```

Comment: There is an issue with your SessionHandler class, so could you add SessionHandler implementation to your question?

Comment: The @Resource notation not part of the Spring ecosystem. So first of all you need to fix your import (change it to 'import javax.annotation.Resource'). This should fix your compilation error.

Comment: @wolle271 Thank you, that did it. That is the issue with using a free editor that give no hints to things like imports.